# Distributing partitions across cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, bigdata, cluster-computing

In `apache spark` one is allowed to load datasets from many different sources. According to my understanding computing nodes of `spark` cluster can be different than these used by `hadoop` to store data (am I right?). What is more, we can even load local file into `spark` job. Here goes main question: Even if we use the same computers for `hdfs` and `spark` purposes, is it always true that `spark`, during creation of `RDD`, will shuffle all data? Or `spark` will just try to load data in the way to take advantage of already existing data locality?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HDFS` as the common underlying storage for both `MapReduce (Hadoop)` and `Spark` engines, and use a cluster manager like `YARN` to perform resource management. `Spark` will try to take advantage of data locality, and execute tasks as close as possible to the data.

*This is how it works*: If data is available on a node to process, but the CPU is not free, Spark will wait for a certain amount of time (determined by the configuration parameter: `spark.locality.wait` seconds, default is 3 seconds) for the CPU to become available.

If CPU is still not free after the configured time has passed, Spark will switch the task to a lower locality level. It will then again wait for `spark.locality.wait` seconds and if a timeout occurs again, it will switch to a yet lower locality level.

The locality levels are defined as below, in order from closest to data, to farthest from data (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskLocality$):

```
PROCESS_LOCAL (data is in the same JVM as the running code)
NODE_LOCAL (data is on the same node)
NO_PREF (data is accessed equally quickly from anywhere and has no locality preference)
RACK_LOCAL (data is on the same rack of servers)
ANY (data is elsewhere on the network and not in the same rack)
```

Waiting time for locality levels can also be individually configured. For longer jobs, the wait time can be increased to a larger value than default of 3 seconds, since the CPU might be tied up longer.